# Why can't I use System.ValueType as a generics constraint?

Tags: c#, generics

- Why can't I use a constraint of
  `where T : System.ValueType`?
- Why does Microsoft prevent this type
  from being a constraint?

---

**Example:**

Why can't I do the following?

```
// Defined in a .Net class
public void bar<T>(T a) where T : ValueType {...}

// Defined in my class
public void foo<T>(T a) where T : ValueType 
{ bar<T>(a); }
```

What is the difference in using struct over ValueType?

```
// Defined in my class
public void foo<T>(T a) where T : struct 
{ bar<T>(a); }
```

Answer (score 75, accepted):

There are two differences between using

```
where T : struct
```

and

```
where T : ValueType
```

- the latter would allow `T` to be `ValueType` itself, which is a reference type.
- the latter would also allow `T` to be a nullable value type

The first of these differences is almost never what you want. The second could *occasionally* be useful; `Nullable<T>` is slightly odd in that it satisfies neither the `where T : struct` nor `where T : class` constraint.

More useful would be the constraint

```
where T : struct, System.Enum
```

which is prohibited by C# for no good reason that I can tell. See [my blog post](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/09/10/generic-constraints-for-enums-and-delegates/) and the [Unconstrained Melody project](http://code.google.com/p/unconstrained-melody/) for more on this.

Comment: I have to say, I've always wondered by we can't limit them like `where T : struct, System.Enum`. It would be *so useful* at times!

Comment: You _can_ actually do `where T: Enum` and `where T: ValueType` in F# (using its syntax `when 'T :> Enum`) and indeed, it works as Jon expects it to work. For the enum-type-constraint, it works with generic enums like `enum<byte>` and `System.Enum`, and correctly forbids synonymous value types like `byte` or `int`. To answer Jon's question to "why" it is so difficult to add to C#, see this Roslyn discussion: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/262

Comment: I got to a place where I actually want to say all concrete implementations of ValueType including nullable. (The actually constraint is where T: ValueType, New)

Comment: It might be surprising at first to hear that `ValueType` is a reference type but it is an *abstract class*.

Answer (score 15):

ValueType is not the base class of value types, it is simply a container for the value when it is boxed. Since it is a container class and not in any sort of hierarchy for the actual types you're wanting to use, it is not useful as a generic constraint.

Comment: Not quite and not completely. In IL you can clearly see the declaration of any value type having `extends System.ValueType`, which makes it effectively the base class. I think its primary role is as marker to distinguish between a class and a value type, but I'm not sure.

Comment: The conclusion ("not useful as a generic constraint") is correct, but the rest of the answer is not.  ValueType "provides the base class for value types."  (from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetype?view=netframework-4.8)  and also  "...It is the base class for all value types..." (from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.isvaluetype?view=netframework-4.8#remarks)

Answer (score 6):

Using `struct` as a generic constraint is functionally equivalent to a "ValueType" constraint.  In .NET, [a struct is a value type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx).

Comment: A struct is a `ValueType`, yes, but not every value type is a struct, for instance, `ValueType` itself is not a struct, nor are nullable value types.

Comment: I don't think this answer is correct, based on the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think the example below covers a lot of use cases that one would expect from ValueType.  The parameter type of T? allows nullables, and the type constraints restrict it to structs that implement IFormattable which is true for the common value types I can think of.

```
public void foo<T>(T? a) where T : struct, IFormattable
```

Note that this allows types such as decimal, datetime, timespan.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iformattable?view=netcore-3.1