# Generics to validate c# method parameters

Tags: c#, .net, validation, generics

So I setup C# parameter validation using the method described in [this](http://johngilliland.wordpress.com/2009/01/07/argument-validation-using-c-30-extension-methods/) blog post. Everything works great for `strings` for which I have this extension method setup at the base of it all:

```
public static ArgumentEx<T> NotEmptyString<T>(this ArgumentEx<T> arg) where T : class
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(arg.Value.ToString()))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("{0} cannot be empty.", arg.Name));
    }
    return arg;
}
```

However, when I try and add an extension method for `ints` to determine if they are less than or equal to zero such as this:

```
public static ArgumentEx<T> NotZeroOrLess<T>(this ArgumentEx<T> arg) where T : class
{
    if (Convert.ToInt32(arg.Value.ToString()) <= 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Please make sure {0} is greater than zero.", arg.Name));
    }
    return arg;
}
```

I get this error when I try and call it like so `userId.RequireThat("userId").NotZeroOrLess();`

> The type 'int' must be a reference type in order to use it as
>   parameter 'T' in the generic type or method

Like I said, doing `name.RequireThat("name").NotEmptyString();` works fine, as `name` is a `string`. I've tried specifying the type for the generic like so:

```
userId.RequireThat<int>("userId").NotZeroOrLess();
```

But I get the same error. I have to admit, I'm not too well versed with generics. Can someone explain why this error is occurring? Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to remove `where T : class` from your extension method `public static ArgumentEx<T> NotZeroOrLess<T>(this ArgumentEx<T> arg) where T : class`?

Comment: That did it, and I understand these things more fully after reading the links Tomas posted as well. However, will removing this cause any problems in the future that I should be aware of?

Answer (score 1):

It is throwing error because you defined class constraint, but int is not a class, it is a value type - struct. Read basics http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx.

Read [Why can't I use System.ValueType as a generics constraint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854625/why-cant-i-use-system-valuetype-as-a-generics-constraint) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for the links Tomas. These things make a little bit more sense now :)